# Reading from text files

Tags: java, file

I need to read data from a text file using Java and currently I am using:

```
public void read()  throws Exception 
{
    FileInputStream in = null;
    try 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner("dataset.txt");
        File inputFile = new File(fileName.nextLine());
        in = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
    } 
    catch ( Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

However, I wish to give the user a choice to read from dataset.txt and data.txt so I tried doing:

```
public void read(int name)  throws Exception 
{
    FileInputStream in = null;
    try 
    {
        File inpu = new File(name.nextLine());
        in = new FileInputStream(input);
    } 
    catch ( Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

but I am getting an error : int cannot be dereferenced

Comment: nextInt() -> return only integer. How could be fileName?

Comment: Which line is throwing this error?

Comment: you're right! how can I go around it?

Comment: How about a string array that contains the two file names (remember that array indices start at 0)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First your code have a lot of errors. I suppose if you are displaying this line on console

```
System.out.print("Please choose a dataset (1) dataset.txt , (2)data.txt : ");
```

User's input is in `int` and you are passing like `fileName.nextLine()`, Which cause an error

try this:

```
Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in));
fileName="";
System.out.print("Please choose a dataset (1) dataset.txt , (2)data.txt : ");
int input = scan.nextInt();
if(input==1){
   fileName="dataset.txt";
}
if(input==2){
   fileName="data.txt";
}
File inputFile=new File(fileName));
... .
```

Answer (score 0):

`fileName` has type `int`. You cannot call methods from primitive types.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only have two different file, why don't you use an `if` statement to see which file the user wants to open and then give that file to your `inputFile` which you can pass to `in`.

```
if (fileName == 1) {
    inputFile = new File("dataset.txt");
} else if (fileName == 2) {
    inputFile = new File("data.txt");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If "name" input variable is the value selected by the user is required to use a condition to select the according file name depending on the user decission

Example:

```
public void read(int name)  throws Exception {
    FileInputStream in = null;
    try  {

        // File selection depending on user number selection
        String fileName="dataSet.txt";
        if(name == 2){
            fileName ="otherFileName.txt";
        }

        // InputStream creation
        File input = new File(fileName);
        in = new FileInputStream(input);

       // Your read operations here

    } catch ( Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

On this example if the user press 2 the "otherFileName.txt" is used. 
Otherwise "dataSet.txt" is used.

Also al files are without path. These means that are required to be in the startup path of the application.